# How custom tag function work with tagged template string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Actually there is no error, just want know how exactly in JavaScript this tag  call as a function and get the string in front of it, in other words want to know how exactly the mentioned code work.

This line is my main question:

```
let str = tag`My age is ${a + b} and I love ${c}`;
```

how the **tag** work as a function in here.

```
let tag = function (strings, ...values) {
    let result = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        result += strings[i];
        if (i < values.length) {
            result += values[i];   
        }
    }
    return result;
};

let a = 20;
let b = 12;
let c = "JavaScript";
let str = tag`My age is ${a + b} and I love ${c}`;
console.log(str);
```

the output is correct which is:
My age is 32 and I love JavaScript

Comment: Described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax:

```
let str = tag`My age is ${a + b} and I love ${c}`;
```

is described [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates).  These are called "tagged templates".  They allow you to add custom function logic that can affect how the template literal result is constructed and the template function gets access to the elements of the parsed template string.

In that above linked MDN reference there are multiple examples of different ways of using tagged templates.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and detailed reply, so its like this
`let tag: (strings: any, ...values: any[]) => string`  
and could say this would be something like: 
`tag (['My age is', ' ', 'and I love', ' '])`

Answer (score -1):

*More examples*

```js
// TAG FUNCTION
greet`I'm ${name}. I'm ${age} years old.`
```

```js
// EQUIVALENT FUNCTION
greet(["I'm ", ". I'm ", " years old."], name, age)
```

```
var name = 'Alfred';
var age = 47;
function greet(arr, nameArg, ageArg) {
  console.log(arr[0] + nameArg + arr[1] + ageArg + arr[2]);
}
greet`Woah, ${name} is ${age}?`;
// "Woah, Alfred is 47?"
```

> https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-are-tag-functions-97682f29521b

---

*For typescript*

```
function merge(template: TemplateStringsArray, ...params: string[]){
}
```

```
// 
// Generic
//
// Tagged template literals can be generic, too.
function generic<T>(template: TemplateStringsArray, ...params: T[]){
    return template.join(",") + params.join(",")
}

// "A value: ,test"
console.log(generic<string>`A value: ${"test"}`);

//
// Generic (with super powers)
//
// You can specify each type and 
// also limit the number of params!
function coalesce<A, B, C>(template: TemplateStringsArray, ...params: [A, B, C]){
    return template.join(",") + params.join(",")
}

// ", - , - ,value,0,true" 
const res = coalesce<string, number, boolean>`${"value"} - ${0} - ${true}`;
```

> https://flaming.codes/posts/typescript-and-javascript-tagged-template-strings